# Reading and select XML tags with XPath query

Tags: xml, xpath

I need to extrapolate a series of values ​​through XPath queries from XML files that I report at end of the page.

Especially thanks to indications received in a previous question, I have the possibility to extrapolate all the values ​​of my interest thanks to the following queries, which I use in an application:

The value of the Tag     IdC -> SelfDescription -> ID with:

```
/ * [Name () = 'IdC'] / * [name () = 'SelfDescription'] / * [name () = 'ID']
```

The values ​​contained in the "Path" Tag with:

```
// * [name () = 'Path']
```

with output

```
docs / 002D4DC0.pdf
docs / 002D4DC2.pdf
docs / 002D4DC4.pdf
docs / 002D4DC6.pdf
```

etc ..

the different values ​​of the TAGs "value" referring to the related group

```
"<File s: format =" application / pdf ">"
```

based on the indexes 1,2,3 with:

```
// m: meta [1] / @ value
// m: meta [2] / @ value
```

etc ..

with output (example)

```
2019-05-06 
2019-05-07
...
```

or

```
9102154402
9102154403
....
```

I can then through other queries in SQL to output a table that returns the data in columns in the desired form, like:

```
ID            Path                   Value1                  Value2
1558224025077 docs / 002D4DC0.pdf    2019-05-06            9102154402
1558224025077 docs / 002D4DC2.pdf    2019-05-07            9102154403
```

etc ..

My problem is that the application that reads the XML in the first phase of the procedure, using the above expressions, is able to process only a limited number of values ​​each time therefore, when the XML contains a large number of data, my final output is incomplete.

It is possible to succeed in making expressions

```
// * [name () = 'Path']
// m: meta [1] / @ value
```

or other appropriate functions Xpath

so that they only operate on a range of tags present in XML, for example from 1 to 100, then from 101 to 200 etc ..?

I tried using the "Position" function for example by writing

/ / * [name () = 'Path'] [position (> 10)]

or similar,

But I do not get the desired result. From what I understand all the values ​​are considered in position = 1.
if I write in the previous expression `[position (= 1)]`
I get all the XML "Path" values, otherwise if I write for example `[position (> 1)]`

I don't find any value. Is there a solution?

Thank you very much in advance who can help me.

XML Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<IdC xmlns="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:s="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.uni.com/U3011/sincro/ UNI1138600_2010_EIT.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd lotto.xsd http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd metadata.xsd">
  <SelfDescription>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1558224025077</ID>
    <CreatingApplication>
      <Name>tDoc</Name>
      <Version>r16610</Version>
      <Producer>Andxor Soluzioni Informatiche srl</Producer>
    </CreatingApplication>
    <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
      <EmbeddedMetadata>
        <lotto xmlns="http://andxor.it/tDoc/lotto.xsd">
          <company>SCOTT</company>
          <doctype>FATTURE_PASSIVE</doctype>
          <period>2019</period>
          <previous id="1557187238227">60AECF9413EE8D53F2238C03D8271670C5761FC5AEE92951966D3BE31FC192E2</previous>
        </lotto>
      </EmbeddedMetadata>
    </MoreInfo>
  </SelfDescription>
  <VdC>
    <ID s:scheme="local">1558224025077</ID>
  </VdC>
  <FileGroup xmlns:m="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2969024</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D4DC0.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">CCB149AA3C63F4B7519A49E0453742FFC63E85CD44DC458BB094D0682A053E40</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-06T19:40:11+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-04-30"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102154398"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2969026</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D4DC2.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">8005A54C5D12219295B3E16CD28A93C3CDB9C9DA67630E20F8DAB749DADF1F56</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-06T19:40:13+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-04-30"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102154402"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2969028</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D4DC4.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">4B516C97B13D5FC7C4D13B27CD08C3B7238292CA19B922EACA002FC3EA5648FF</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-06T19:40:15+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-04-30"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102154401"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2969030</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D4DC6.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">98DFE554FFE5E915819CD65DE144F87A987B44B087FFFD2D65CFD17CD83AE54F</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-06T19:40:17+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-04-30"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102154403"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971559</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57A7.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">84E6FA2DE5BC6C76FFD964676BA3A489C22CCE3437E09A11BCA162CBEA5DE1E0</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:15+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164873"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971561</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57A9.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">D597B29A835DA8D652D37E504B244B526815BD14C9DCDEF36B9CE951691E99A0</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:16+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164874"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971563</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57AB.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">1511BC54E9B5B5C23AB66C2CF7289829674674E4291B8A0B1F94BA553012F944</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:19+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164878"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971565</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57AD.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">C6A1B7437636F56A2FD944DA2DA966B47F00D5E7F42687B9F56F47166595558B</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:20+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164871"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971567</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57AF.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">855AF9E5A35988DFF3E78251E71FA0E272273975CEB0F5E2040CBD971198DF2D</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:23+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164869"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971569</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57B1.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">722289B51FB0D66066CB93C47FFA73578F97272DF0205974B3F20C756B27CE30</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:57:24+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164875"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971571</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57B3.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">FB8D7657402CBAA4644C48BD31D96F0D42BC3AFCFA3E1F03FEBE58627D64E055</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:08+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164882"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971573</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57B5.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">D265E85C19B8BCFD3F4A55D05EC84959C05D886E1F55A9714BD6479C4465160A</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:09+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164886"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971575</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57B7.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">F3692962D9BBDA21FC4EE74C1235A0D43DC28576F20B34D96D5B0CB3561CD985</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:10+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164884"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971577</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57B9.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">7B818CF3587FC11E39AEA91DC0E47CE13A7272CC8B62C311C4C779171B6C86BB</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:12+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164881"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971579</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57BB.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">26E455FFC70B8C68F96CE1D0A01320D9E79659DB6104CFD3746FFA9905AA0848</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:13+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164883"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971581</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57BD.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">68CD2CB7EAB47A4D355C313E247B1AA767C1A770065735AC48DB671E4CCF3101</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:15+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164880"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971583</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57BF.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">A2272100933748D013482DC6FF21E085F18AE21A173E27FD8CBEB5F458A9F418</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:16+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-13"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200010"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164889"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971585</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57C1.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">E11257E423CEFFCE97720B700F078D6AA5A91420C2813549F0D6145CA5A24A38</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:17+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164887"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971587</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57C3.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">BA9DA8EFC6F57FCC5212B1B553B8E34E250F15EDB684941A32708DB200B2868A</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:19+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164888"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971589</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57C5.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">8622BEB8816D53CCEC44F32F381FC072760D6BC01995CBB6D9BCF748050B8BB1</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:58:21+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-10"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200009"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164885"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971591</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57C7.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">A9076E11BD03952FC2D610438E789D963E9461B6331A9DDB6649979A97487BFE</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:59:10+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-13"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200010"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164891"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
    <File s:format="application/pdf">
      <ID s:scheme="local">2971593</ID>
      <Path>docs/002D57C9.pdf</Path>
      <Hash s:function="SHA-256">70FECF3F3186552114D14AF57829BE76AA6F0FFC3473F620F2CA0B9B00E74712</Hash>
      <MoreInfo s:XMLScheme="http://andxor.it/tDoc/metadata.xsd">
        <EmbeddedMetadata>
          <m:metadata>
            <m:meta class="internal" name="Data inserimento" value="2019-05-13T20:59:11+02:00"/>
            <m:meta name="Data" value="2019-05-13"/>
            <m:meta name="Ragione Sociale" value="SCOTT ITALIA S.R.L."/>
            <m:meta name="Codice Cliente" value="200010"/>
            <m:meta name="Partita Iva" value="IT03770200164"/>
            <m:meta name="Numero Protocollo" value="9102164890"/>
          </m:metadata>
        </EmbeddedMetadata>
      </MoreInfo>
    </File>
  </FileGroup>
  <Process>
    <Agent s:type="organization" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <FormalName>KPNQwest Italia SpA</FormalName>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">07957860153</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Giuseppe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Baccanelli</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">BCCGPP64C01A940D</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="person" s:role="PreservationManager">
      <AgentName>
        <NameAndSurname>
          <FirstName>Giuseppe</FirstName>
          <LastName>Baccanelli</LastName>
        </NameAndSurname>
      </AgentName>
      <Agent_ID s:scheme="TaxCode">BCCGPP64C01A940D</Agent_ID>
    </Agent>
    <Agent s:type="organization" s:role="OtherRole" s:otherRole="Other role">
      <AgentName>
        <FormalName>Amministratore</FormalName>
      </AgentName>
    </Agent>
    <TimeReference>
      <TimeInfo>2019-05-19T02:00:25+02:00</TimeInfo>
    </TimeReference>
    <LawAndRegulations s:language="it">DPCM 3 dicembre 2013</LawAndRegulations>
  </Process>
</IdC>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath syntax is wrong. You should use `()` around the first part of your selector and declare `position()` correctly with :

```
(//*[name()="Path"])[position()>9 and position()<21]
```

With your sample data, this will select `Path` elements from the 10th to the 20 th position.

Comment: Good morning
It works perfectly, thank you for the very useful indication

bye